# How do you resolve a $q.reject promise from a then block in unit testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Here is my test, but I'm having the problem that neither my success nor reject functions are being hit. If I resolve the Http promise with good data, then my success function is hit (which then throws the exception "this should not be hit"). I'm expecting the error handler to be hit when bad data does in, but it never does. What am I doing wrong?

```
it("should resolve to failure action", function(done){
    Service.load().then(function(){
        throw new Exception("This should not be hit");
    }, function(){
        done();
    });

    $http.post.resolve(badData);
});


// mean while, the Service.load function
load: function(){
    return this.getHttpPromise().then(function(data){
        // process our data
        if(data.isGood)
            return data;

        return $q.reject("Data is not good");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like after a while I managed to figure this out. In my unit test, instead of calling $rootScope.$digest, or $scope.$digest, I needed to call $timeout.flush();